# Как добавить дату без времени в БД использую JDBC

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, дата, время

```
protected void inserToDBincome(int value){
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bookkeeping (Date, income) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, value);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

В данном куске кода добавляется нынешняя дата и время в формате 2017-12-02 12:44:47, мне нужно, чтобы была просто дата

Comment: Так вы поле в таблице объявите как date, а не timestamp.

Comment: Хорошо, а дальше что?

Comment: А дальше либо `java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date(); preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(today.getTime()))`, либо так, как я вас ответил в прошлом вопросе.

Comment: Благодарю! Данный способ помог)